# What would an Earth with no timezones be like?

Tags: time, modern-age

If we abolished the system of time zones, and everywhere followed UTC (or another arbitrary timezone), what would the possible advantages or disadvantages of this system be? If you can think of any specific activities that would be disrupted or enhanced due to this, please include those as examples!

Comment: This feels almost Idea Generation, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: You mean like [@beats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time)? They actually tested this; it uses a metric system (1000 beats per day, or 86.4 seconds per beat), and had people use a watch that read in beats. The test subjects were very quick to adapt to a singular coordinated time.

Comment: Using UTC the world over might get people to realizing that clock time is something that has only a passing relationship to the phenomenon of time itself.

Comment: I once read an article that claimed people in Texas do the same things as people in New York, they just call it be different names.  For example, *arrive at work* is called 8:30am in New York, and 7:30am in Texas, but is really the same time. Here's the [article](http://qz.com/142199/the-us-needs-to-retire-daylight-savings-and-just-have-two-time-zones-one-hour-apart/)

Comment: I am in disagreement that this should be closed, as we have questions related to eternal day or night planets. A cultural, geological, or astronomical phenomenon of a shared timezone doesn't seem that far off from those other questions, and the answers aren't so broad since timekeeping is so coupled with business and networking and living beings' habits. I'm just throwing my two cents in.

Comment: @Anathema the difference is this is the real world...without any alteration other than something that has been actively investigated and proposed in the real world.

Comment: One of many.  https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/wonkblog/post/should-we-get-rid-of-time-zones/2012/03/16/gIQAtGJpIS_blog.html

Comment: @James I feel like the process to reach a shared timezone and the planet in question is irrelevant. OP could have posted any planet or any method/setting and if it led to a shared timezone then the spirit of the question and its ramifications on culture would remain the same.

Comment: I think this article is highly relevant: [So you want to abolish time zones](http://qntm.org/abolish)

Comment: Why would you want to? So you don't have to do a short calculation to know what the hour is in another part of the world? But now you have to do a lengthy calculation to figure out what time of day it is.
I know what I am usually doing at 2am, so if I figure it's someone else's 2am I won't call them. (as a rule)
If it's 2am am everywhere simultaneously, how do I know for whom that's the middle of the night and where it's the middle of the day.

Comment: @2012rcampion that article is becoming less relevant every day.  pretty soon, if i want to call my uncle, i could just ask siri if now is a good time to call him. in fact, even without timezones, the author would not have known when to call him without siri's help since his uncle was planning on sleeping until solar noon.

Comment: In short: If you removed time zones, you would remove the time on the clock from the meaning for the people using it. With Noon being 12:00, you have a rough hint when talking about time where approximately this point is in reference to getting up, lunch, and going to bed, for example.
Without this relation, the exact time would be meaning less for many day to day things and a different reference frame would need to be added.

Comment: And what happens with 'yesterday', 'today' and 'tomorrow' then?

Comment: Software development time would be cut in half.

Comment: 9 to 5 jobs will grow even less popular in Australia.

Comment: @2012rcampion That article would be relevant if it wasn't complete garbage. I read the entire thing and honestly, his points are straw man arguments at best.

Comment: @talex: Nothing happens. Those terms already have different meanings depending on context and calendar. Some people change the date at sundown. Others at sunup. Others at midnight. Others at midday. For most people, "today" means "this waking period" regardless of whether it spans two calendar dates. Alternately, it could refer to "this work shift" in a professional context. Usually, context makes it clear which definition we're using, but sometimes we specify as needed.

Comment: The real problem starts to show up when you run into days, I go to sleep on tuesday wake up on tuesday and drive to work and 4 hours into work it becomes wednesday. Now lets say I live in NY and you send me an email important meeting tomorrow. I go home go to sleep wake up and go to work then after you call me and ask why I didn't log into the meeting and I say it isn't tomorrow yet its still the same day you called me. UTC also means univeral days, which is just confusing.

Comment: Where is the research Worldbuilding SE asks of you?

Answer (score 61):

For their day to day lives, people in different parts of the world would associate different times with different activities. While to someone in Greenwich 11:30 am might mean "lunch time", to people in the Eastern US it might mean "time to wake up", to others it might be "dinner time", or "middle of the night".

No doubt if time zones were abolished tomorrow, people would find it very confusing for a while. But I presume that after, what, a few years?, people would get used to it, and the idea that the sun rises at around 3:00 pm seem natural and familiar.

Once people were used to it, the only time when it would make a difference would be when someone travels to other parts of the world or talks to someone from other parts of the world. Today, for most of us there is some confusion when talking to someone far away as to what time of day it is for them. When it's 10:00 am at my home, what time is it in Tokyo? Etc. If there were no time zones, then this question would be meaningless. If it's 10:00 am here, then OF COURSE it's 10:00 am everywhere in the world.

But you'd still have to think about where the other person is in their daily cycle. When I ask, "When it's 10:00 am here, what time is it in Tokyo?", my reason for asking is likely to be, "Is this a reasonable time to call, or will it be the middle of the night over there?" You'd still have that problem. Well, I'm assuming that when you say there are no time zones, you're not thinking that everyone works to the same schedule. That, say, if people in London begin the workday at 9:00 am, that this means that everyone begins the workday at 9:00 am, even people for whom that is the middle of the night.

So on the one hand it could be simpler. We don't have to ask what time zone a person is in, because there's only one. If someone says, "the meeting is at 2:00 pm" or "the train leaves at 2:00 pm" or whatever, we don't have to ask what time zone. It could eliminate a lot of potential confusion. For people who regularly work with schedules across multiple time zones -- like people at railroads and airlines -- this could avoid a lot of potential confusion. I'm a software developer, and every now and then I work with computers located in different time zones, and this can get confusing. Like if I check a computer and see that a certain file was last updated at 3:00, is that my local time, or the time where that computer is located? And where is that computer physically located? Sometimes I don't even know. Etc.

On the other hand, it could make it more difficult to talk about different daily schedules. With time zones, it's easy to say "when it's 9:00 am here it's 4:00 pm in Tokyo", and we now have a good idea how our daily schedule relates to theirs. But with no time zones, how would you express this idea? You'd have to say things like, "people there usually start work at 4:00 pm". Then if you want to know when they might have lunch or go home from work or go to bed, you'd have to count hours from start of the day for you, and add it to their start time, and so do a bunch of arithmetic in your head, which could get awkward.

So, I'd say pros and cons.

Comment: All file systems should record the 'last updated' time in UTC. Some don't. I feel your pain.

Comment: Well you wouldn't use PM - that's already a relative measurement from local noon..."post meridian".  If everyone used Zulu (GMT time) you just would need to know when noon was in Zulu at any location you are interested in.  For instance, the Central Time Zone is +6 hours from Zulu.

Comment: @Oldcat CST is UTC-6, not UTC+6

Comment: @oldcat Well, okay, maybe we'd use a 24 hour clock, which I think would simplify things all around anyway. But that's a different issue. If we used a 12 hour clock, arguably am/pm doesn't really make sense, but I doubt we'd invent another word for it, it would just become one of those terms that people would say "yes, it doesn't make literal sense, but it takes back to those primitive times when", etc. Like "clockwise" doesn't make sense to people who use only digital clocks.

Comment: @Oldcat Yes, you could say, "for them noon (i.e. sun at its highest point) is at 1400 hours". But my point is, today if someone from a faraway place says "this happened at 6:00 pm", I have a good idea where that fit in their daily cycle. If there were no time zones and someone said it happened at 6:00 pm (or 1800 hours), even knowing that noon for them is 3:00 am, I have to do some arithmetic in my head. Mind-boggling complex math? No. But an extra nuisance. More or less nuisance than time zones? Hard to say.

Comment: If you have a worldwide universal clock, you are more or less saying that "what the position of the sun at place X now"  is way less important than "when does this worldwide event happen in absolute terms" and your measures fit that.  So if you want to know if people will be asleep, then the current measures are better.  If you want to know when to log into Youtube for a LiveStream in Thailand, the Zulu time would be much easier, as you can look at its time and compare it to your zulu clock on the wall.

Comment: Before timezones, every town would set its clocks to local noon, so everyones time was exact to the sun and unknowable to everyone else.  Today we figure 1 hour of slop in solar noon to clock noon is acceptable.

Comment: I would like to point out that schedules vary across countries, and sometimes even firms/individuals. As a French, I'm always surprised when watching American movies because they get up much earlier than I do and, on the other hand, eat dinner much sooner, with regard to their local time.

Comment: "the train leaves at 2:00 pm" - plane might be a better example, trains don't cross time zones so often or so fast. Also, airlines already work by UTC, so no real change for them anyway.

Comment: @molot Trains don't cross time zones as quickly, but they still cross them regularly, and it only takes a train crossing a time zone once in it's travel to create a potential for confusion. And airlines certainly do discuss schedules in local time: visit any airline website or look at the arrival and departure board at the airport and to the best of my knowledge they are always expressed in local time. Airline agents talking to customers give times in local time. Maybe in purely internal conversations they use UTC, so there might be LESS change, but not NONE.

Comment: @Oldcat: Apparently, some think only 30 minutes are acceptable.

Comment: I dont think that we need years to adapt to UTC time. I dont think that adapting to UTC will be any worse than adapting back and forth from daylight saving time. I say gove it two weeks and everyone is back to sync. You dont need to change any habit of yours ir anything. You just need ro shift your thinking a little bit and populations already dealt with let's say currency changes wich also require little shift of thinking

Comment: Insofar as needing to know when someone is available elsewhere, there is now a very simple solution: you ask them. No math/google required. You will know, when they say it, _immediately_ how that relates to your own day, and vice versa for them.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer But when do you ask them? I really wouldn't want someone to call me at 2:00 in the morning to ask, "What would be a good time for you to have a business call today?"

Comment: Note that aviation *does* use UTC. We just convert to/from local time when talking with the general public. Most computers also work in UTC internally and with each other but convert to/from local time for humans users.

Answer (score 38):

Look at China.  China *already* abolished timezones (within the boundaries of the country).

The result would be that "9am" is not breakfast for everyone, instead "9am" would be an objective point in the day at which different people do different things.

So for you, living in California (for example) with the UTC model, "9am" is the middle of the night.  You won't be up until 3pm, leaving for work by 4pm, getting there at 5pm, and working until 2am.  All during the daylight hours.

Whereas for someone living in the UK "9am" would approximately be when they get to work.

This would cause more headaches than it solves, as your UK compatriot would send you an email asking for an 11am conference call and you're reply would be "That's the middle of the night!"  Oh, he replies, *what's the time difference?* and you have no reply because the concept of time zones is dead.

Comment: I never realized that getting rid of time zones would actually make it harder to plan meetings across time zones. I always thought that everyone using a common time would be futuristic, but now I'm just thinking about people trying to figure out what time it is by comparing the position of the sun, or how long it's been since breakfast, and it sounds like a terrible idea. In other words, +1.

Comment: It *barely* holds together in China, and that's only got five (standard) timezones to deal with.  And the only reason it's kept is because the government is a borderline dictatorship.  Whatever the Communist party wants the Communist party gets and someone decided that having everyone use the same timezone would be the best of ideas.  And so the common folk suffer with pre-dawn 9ams.

Comment: While a smaller scale, Alaska has the same thing -- geographically, we span 4 timezones, but legally we have only 2 (Alaska, 1 hour behind Pacific, and Aleutian/Hawaiian, another hour behind that). It leads to anomalies such as Anchorage seeing sunset at ~11:40 PM on the summer solstice (solar time: 9:41 PM) while Fairbanks sees the same thing at ~12:45 the next day! And on the winter solstice, the sun doesn't rise in Nome until after noon! Of course, when Fairbanks sees as little as 3 hours 42 minutes of daylight, and as much as almost 22 hours, sunrise/sunset have little meaning to us...

Comment: @Kromey To be fair, that far north the clock stops making sense (with the sun's actions) anyway!  Only a little farther and the sun won't set at all!

Comment: The upshot of my comment (ran out of space) being that things like "pre-dawn 9ams" really aren't that big a deal. I get to work at 8am, whether the sun's up or not, and I work until 5pm, whether the sun's set already or not. What is a big deal, though, is that when I try to coordinate with European contacts, I'm getting to work at 8am my time, which is 5pm (give or take depending on country) over there -- and that would only be worse if we're both technically on the same time, but I'm going to work at 5pm whiel they're clocking off at 5pm.

Comment: @Draco18s True, but the point being that disconnecting the "real" clock from the solar clock isn't all that big deal really. (Barrow gets, contrary to what the movie tells you, 67 days with no sun at all!)

Comment: Very true.  And while people do have to deal with it, the *whole world* doing it would be absurd.  There's no point in trying to force the States to operate on UTC with 9pm sunrises and going to work in the middle of the night, making them skip out on the daylight hours "just because that's what time the clocks say it is" (having worked the nightshift: it plays hell on your psyche).  When nature itself throws you the middle finger, you deal with it because there is no other option than to move to the lower latitudes.

Comment: I would think that if there were only one time zone, then we would all be using 24 hour clocks, not AM and PM.

Comment: @DavidK doesn't really change the notion that people in different areas of the world will still be sleeping at 09:00 while you rise and break your fast at that time...

Comment: @Draco18s: I don't see why that matters. It's just a number. Plenty of people are already sleeping habitually at 9am. So what?

Comment: I think your conversation might go more like, "*conference call at 11am?*" "I am asleep at that time!" "*What times are you available?*" "I'm available [these times] - (*which the caller compares with the times he is available - rather than converting to his timezone and then comparing*). The hindrance occurs when trying to plan a meeting time under some assumptions - when you don't have contact with the other person but you know their location and thus what time they *should* be available - such as "*he should be in the office between 8 and 5 his time which is [x] my time*"

Comment: Instead of "what's the time difference", you could ask "at what time is midnight at your place?"

Comment: Yeah, "solar offset" could serve to distinguish relative noon/midnight timing.

Comment: Also when travelling into a different timezime currently, you adjust your watch and once your internal clock has adjusted too, everything seems normal again. If you travel half way around the world and you now have to get up at 02:00 instead of 14:00, etc. that would be much harder to get used to. Travelling to an area where people do things slightly earlier or later, like the French example starting work at 10:00 instead of 9:00 is easier when it's a small amount of time from the "normal" time.

Comment: Worth a read with respect to the introductory paragraph: [*Xinjiang Time - A Tale of Two Time Zones*](http://www.farwestchina.com/2015/02/xinjiang-time-a-tale-of-two-time-zones.html)

Comment: How would it create headaches? It would solve headaches because you dont need to re-calculate the "11am conference" but you simply know where it is because everywhere on earth would be 11am on the same time. Whan you are an american you wouldn't know what I as a german would mean by 11am - most likely you would need to look up what timezone I am in and wheather or not any special rules (such as daylight saving time) apply or not

Comment: @JonasDralle "I'm sorry, I live in Japan, I go to bed at 10am."

Comment: @Draco18s then your business partner needs to give a conference termin that suites your well. This isnt a problem with UTC time but rathet with the example given by Draco18s

Comment: @JonasDralle Making the entire world operate on a single time zone introduces ambiguity ("what is 10am?") into a system that is already hard enough to deal with on an international scale.

Comment: Whatever happened to "Effective Jan 1, 2019 I will cease providing content for SE Inc to monetize"?

Answer (score 21):

For one serious difficulty, look to people working night shifts, where the date switches over in the middle of the night.

Knowing what time you go to work is easy. The difficulty is with what date you are on. We are all used to the date changing at midnight, when most people are asleep. The next day, you date any papers with a new date, that you keep for the entire waking cycle.

In the new system you have to change the date at midnight UTC. Depending on where you are, this could be a couple hours before the solar clock reaches noon. It's very unintuitive, and gives people in this situation something extra to think about. As a result, it would cause problems, even among people used to it. It is already somewhat difficult to keep track of a current date. Changing it midway through the waking cycle just adds confusion.

From personal experience, I worked an overnight shift where we had to record the time of certain events, ending at dawn. When the day switched over at midnight, we technically switched dates. In practice, when we wrote 1AM, July 18th, it was 1AM of the night that started on July 18th. We had tried changing dates at midnight, but even using a computer that told up the actual date, people made frequent mistakes, often continuing to use the previous date all night long. It meant a lot of going through the paperwork to correct dates. Not changing dates midway through the worknight saved a lot of trouble.

Comment: I love this, totally makes sense, had not occurred to me at all.

Comment: TV channels already sometimes have this problem, where they have to describe something happening at "1am on Saturday night / Sunday morning", because they feel "1am Sunday" wouldn't make sufficient sense to somebody who thinks as "Saturday" as occurring from when they get up Saturday morning to whenever they go to bed the following night. The danger with writing "1AM July 18th" to mean `2016-07-19T01:00`, is that if your writing is ever divorced from its original context then all the errors hit anyway. But as you say that risk might still be better than *definitely* making errors all the time.

Comment: Generally, I see people just write "shift started 18 July, 8 PM", "first entry, 9 PM", "second entry, 1 AM", etc. In some of my hospital records, there's an entry before the first log after midnight expressing the new date, then everything after is just the time.

Comment: You can fix this by using 24:00, 25:00, etc. 25:00 on July 18th unambiguously means the same as 1:00 on July 19th.

Answer (score 5):

Why abolish just the timezones? Timezones are merely a tool to more-or-less successfully force "day", a time unit based on Earth rotation, into conformance with local solar time.

I'd say - get rid of this geocentric nonsense alltogether!

Welcome kiloseconds and ultimately metric society! Think of Unix time - just a number, ticking arbitrarily and not being tied to timezones, planet rotation, moon orbits nor planetary orbits.

Plot twist: it works perfectly even between different planets, moons and space stations. For a distributed society it would be a big advantage.

Comment: in different planets, the lightspeed limitations would prevent its actually being used.

Comment: @Mary The time doesn't change on distance, it changes on velocity. So a distant planet can still use the same time. A ship traveling between those would have a discrepancy, but it will show up no matter what kind of time measurement you're using.

Comment: It is impossible to synchronize, because the signal can go only at light speed.

Comment: @Mary If you know the distance and speed, you can calculate the offset and apply correction.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, if timezones are abolished and UTC time used everywhere then we would also need to simultaneously abolish the use of 12-hour time, i.e. AM and PM, as this is now redundant and confusing terminology and use 24-hour time instead.

Secondly we currently use time as an indicator of the local day/night cycle as well as measuring the passage of time. For example if someone tells you it's 6 AM where they are, then you know that roughly speaking this will be around dawn / early morning. However using only UTC if someone tells you it's 06:00 then it is 06:00 for both of you, but is it dawn or dusk where they are? I think people would still need a secondary system for indicating relative time of day in their locality.

Working in IT I can say that timezones are a major headache in software applications, as they are defined by legislation and can be changed arbitrarily. This is one reason UTC is popular in software applications.

Comment: I've heard of the nightmare of working in the scheduling department at Hoover Dam. Some of the workers are from California (Pacific), some are from Nevada (Mountain). California goes on daylight savings, Nevada doesn't... And to make it even more fun, IIRC, the Native American workers who live on reservations in the area do follow daylight savings.  So... yea.

Comment: @MichaelT  I don't think that is correct.  Nevada does have daylight savings and is on Pacific time.  Maybe you are thinking of Arizona?  Arizona does not have daylight savings and uses Mountain time.  Note that Hoover Dam is on the border between Nevada and Arizona, more than an hour from the California border by car.  This may change next year, as Nevada has asked to switch to PDT year round, effectively the same as Arizona (MST year round).

Comment: And the stupid date line could be straightened out at last. I write software to calculate flight paths of objects, and make sure they don't intersect scheduled flight corridors and so. That thing causes me so much trouble.

Comment: @Brythan You are right, I was thinking of the wrong pair of states... it is Nevada and Arizona.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways this could go. Most of the answers assume that all timezones but one (generally GMT/UTC) are abolished and all our clocks are set to the same time. People will just have to get used to having breakfast at midnight, or going to bed at 2pm, if they are unlucky to live in a place where that is the custom.

But the other way would be to return to astronomically correct time, wherever you are. In normal rural life, ... no problem. If you have to communicate with another location, you need to calculate the correct time wherever they are - for example, in Bristol you'd better turn the TV on at 5:40pm to catch the 6 o'clock News from London.

Then there's the discrepancy between solar time and mean time, defined by the [Equation of Time.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time) Your clocks (which drift) run on Mean Time, but your sundial (which is accurate) reports solar time, and they can be up to 15 minutes apart in either direction at different times of the year, so even in one location you need to convert from one to the other with a calendar and a pocket calculator...

What *day* it is - now that's a whole different problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

**on the plus side:** almost everything that uses timezones would be simpler. specifically, when traveling or communicating across timezones. this includes reading things written in another timezone. 
notable examples include:

1. booking airfare
2. scheduling distant meetings (either via telecommunications or travel)
3. setting clocks (since daylight savings time wouldn't make sense and clocks could come pre-set)
4. knowing when emails, text messages and internet messages were sent
5. writing software of almost any kind (software frequently uses timestamps)

**on the down side:**

1. it might be harder to predict when stores open and close. e.g. at some longitude 7-eleven stores would switch from opening at 7am to 6am. this would probably follow political boundaries like state lines much like timezones, but be determined on a chain-by-chain basis rather than state-by-state basis. of course, now that we have google maps, that would be much less of an issue.
2. also, once you have gotten past your jet-lag, it might be slightly more confusing to make dinner reservations because you might not know off hand when you will be hungry, that is however a very minor pause rather than a big issue.
3. lastly, determining when businesses would be open (and people are awake) in distant places would be different. instead of checking the timezone offset and assuming 9-5, there would probably be an official state "business hours". this system would in fact be more effective since not all regions use 9-5. e.g. "temperate" latitudes tend to be closer to 8-4 to optimize daylight during commute, while tropical climates tend towards 10-6 to minimize commuting during the afternoon heat. some regions have longer split work-days with long lunch/rest breaks in the middle, while other regions have shorter workdays due to labor laws.

**side note regarding decimal time:**

on the whole, humans are unlikely to eliminate timezones until we switch to a decimal timekeeping system. both "french republican calendar" and its modern revival "internet beats" use timezone-free decimal clocks whose date flip happens in sync with traditional france time (gmt+1:00).  unfortunately, decimal time seems unlikely to gain broader usage until we have a non-trivial polar or non-earth population. even then, there are likely to be several decades during which both systems are used (e.g. today we use 12hr and 24hr clocks). also, emerging technologies make the transition easier every year.  e.g. soon you will be able to ask siri "when would be a good time to call my uncle in japan?", and she will consider average local business hours as well as when your uncle specifically tends to have online activity. meanwhile, if you would like to start using a decimal clock, there are several mobile apps for it. unfortunately, most of those clocks will shift around as you move between timezones. oddly enough, the only decimal clock app i have found that allows you to lock the timezone is the startrek clock app, since one version of "stardate" was essentially the french revolutionary system.

Comment: Business hours and bank hours get even more awkward than you've depicted. If you deposit at 11:50 PM and withdraw at 12:10 AM, has it been in the bank a day? Well, that's absurd since banks aren't open those hours. But if its UTC based, in Hawaii one could do something like that.

Comment: it doesn't seem awkward to me. the cut-off for deposits at my bank is 5pm eastern. so if i got to the bank at 4:49pm eastern to make a deposit, then in 2 minutes and make a withdrawal, the bank will consider the funds "in the account" for 1 day when calculating my average daily balance.  without timezones, this cut-off would probably be at the start of the day for every bank in the world, rather than varying from 3pm to midnight local time depending on the bank.

Comment: You mean 4:59 pm unless where you live you have 50 minute hours!

Comment: lol. indeed i do :) hard to remember how many units you need to rollup when you aren't using decimal time ;)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it would be very like the situation with months that we have now. In the UK, January is considered likely to be cold, possibly snowy, and generally a really bad time to have a barbecue. In New Zealand, January is early summer, warm, sunny, and absolutely ideal for barbecues.

In the same way, if everyone worked on UTC, the UK would be pretty much unaffected (work starts at 9am, and goes on until 5pm, or something like that). Australia would effectively flip AM and PM, so work starts at 9pm, and goes on until 5am - someone starting work at 9am there is on a night shift, and someone working at 5pm is gearing up for the breakfast rush. It would take a little getting used to, but people have adjusted to a lot more (Christmas on the beach!)

The more interesting changes are all the places in between. In the west coast of the USA, 1pm would be the starting time (roughly), but there would probably be some determination of what a reasonable work time was, either from the top down (government says a reasonable working day is 8 hours between X and Y), or from businesses choosing when seems reasonable, and everyone else fitting with them.

In an ideal world, businesses might take the switch as an opportunity to desync with the local rush hours - there is a lot of cultural inertia behind the idea of "9 to 5", but if local businesses worked a wider range of start times, then peak traffic could be spread across a wider timespan. That would reduce jams, but would rely on businesses being willing to take a risk on being out of sync with others in the area. It's fine if you start a bit before your main customers do, unless they often have issues last thing in the day!

In *our* world, though, I suspect that businesses would stick to exactly the hours they work now, just with different names. Working 9-5 would happen in the UK and Australia, but working 1 til 9 is still a way to make a livin'

Answer (score 2):

Here are two things that nobody seems to have touched on: the definition of days of the week; and related *resistance* to the change.

How do you define a "day"? To put it another way, what is "Monday"? Is it a 24-hour period starting at 00:00 and ending at 24:00? If that's so, then Russ from Auckland never "works Mondays". He starts work at 21:00 Sunday and knocks off at 05:00 Monday. Meanwhile, Mona from San Francisco starts her working week at 17:00 Monday and doesn't finish until 01:00 Tuesday.

The most plausible alternative is a "mixed" system, whereby day names are associated with local solar days, regardless of the time. This is going to be annoying and inconsistent, but it does have a certain advantage. Let's say you wake up "Monday morning" in Auckland, in the early morning light at 19:00. When 24:00, noon, rolls around, what comes next?

- If Monday means the local solar day, then "Monday morning" is followed by "Monday afternoon".
- If Monday means 00:00 to 24:00, then "Monday morning" in Auckland is followed by "*Tuesday* afternoon"!

And then there's a the second point: cultural, and especially religious, resistance to this change. (Don't underestimate this; it's arguably what sank metric time in Revolutionary France.)

Let's say Russ goes to church on Sunday morning, at 22:00. He's already been observing the Sabbath for 22 hours, and his friends who go to the evening service went *before* him, not *after* like they did in the old days. It's also awkward when the service is followed by a church lunch that runs into *Monday* afternoon. But that's not what really bothers his conscience. He knows that in his grandparents' day, they observed the Sabbath from (what he now calls) 12:00 Saturday until 12:00 Sunday. Is his church really keeping the Sabbath? It's the Seventh-Day Adventists all over again! And what do they do with Good "Friday"?

Judaism may have an easier time of it, because the Shabbat is already technically observed according to a *conversion* of systems: it just so happens that the last day of the Hebrew week starts on what we presently call "Friday". So Mona, who's Jewish, observes Shabbat from 02:00 (sunset) on Saturday until 02:00 on Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

Cory Doctorow's free (released under a Creative Commons license) book ["Eastern Standard Tribe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Standard_Tribe) describes a related situation.

In the story, people belong to "tribes" that share a reference timezone, e.g. the Eastern Standard Tribe, whose reference time is according to the EST timezone. All people who belong to a tribe try to maintain a circadian wake-sleep cycle appropriate for that timezone, regardless of where they physically reside.

Advantages of this culture include making the communication among members of a tribe straightforward, and eliminating the jet lag and related hassle when physically travelling. But, as might be expected, the situation creates animosity between the different tribes, each of them, in a sense, living in a parallel world. Also, in each latitude, the tribe whose timezone best fits the human body's natural circadian rhythm is better adapted, and has a "home advantage".

ADDENDUM (trying to better relate to the question):
I don't remember the history of the world in the story (and I'm not sure it was explored), but I assume that people tried to abolish time zones, like the OP suggested, but failed to do so. Instead, there arose a competing set of <strike>standards</strike> tribes, where each tribe enjoys the advantages of the abolition within itself.
One might conjecture that later in the history of that world, a single tribe would emerge victorious and impose its timezone upon the rest, thus leading to the world in the question.

Comment: Welcome to the site yoni, while interesting this is more commentary than an answer to the question.  Please take a moment to edit and address the question posed in the OP.

Comment: @James, did what I could to elaborate the answer, and better fit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

One problem with UTC everywhere is that Europe would be advantaged by having days that change during the nightly inactivity.  It is easier to plan with.  Other continents would switch date during the day.  This would be perceived as "timezone colonialism", imposing the time that is convenient to Europeans at the expense of making it confusing everywhere else.

So nobody would be willing to accept that.  If a single timezone were to be imposed over the world there would be unending debates as to which timezone should be used by all, everybody trying to explain why "my timezone is better than yours".

One more egalitarian option would be to use sidereal time, the time according to the stars.  It would look like the timezone shifts continuously around the clock over the year.  If noon is in the middle of the (solar) day in summer, then it will be in the middle of the night in winter.  Every region on Earth would enjoy a couple of months where the solar day aligns with the calendar days.

I am not sure it will actually help to reduce confusion.  Actually I am sure it will not help to reduce confusion.  Think of train timetables!  But it is egalitarian.  If one time should be adopted by all it could be well that sidereal time gets the least opposition, along the lines of "if it gets messy for me, I want it to be messy for everybody".

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can get rid of time zones without problems is if you could remove the dependence on the sun.

This is impractical on Earth.

**So other options:**
If we were ever to try to colonize Titan, the sun would just be a bright star in the sky. It's also really really cold there.
It does have an atmosphere, which makes it attractive to colonizing though.
So you make it possible by orbiting several fusion reactors around the planet. Because they are ringing the planet, you could light the entire surface at once, and turn the fusion up or down to simulate day/night. Maybe refuel the reactors at night.
Since the entire planet is lit evenly, you could just have a single time that everyone uses.

A multi generation ship would have to be pretty big.
In a space ship, there would be no day or night, just ship time.
Not quite a world, but if it was big enough it could feel like it...

Comment: Titan still has day and night.  Although the Sun is roughly 100 times dimmer when seen from Titan, it is still far brighter than any other star in the sky.  Compare the day and night sides in [this NASA image](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA11548).  (Do note though that the day/night cycle is something like 380 hours long.)

Answer (score 1):

There was already a world without timezones for a longer time than with. Before the railroad occured, every place in the civilized world defined 12:00 as the time where the sun was on it highest point. But as railway transportation took place, it was nesseccary to have one national time just to be able to create schedules for it. So the real deal would be not to change for UTC, instead it would be right to change to real local time! Today this would be no problem at all, because we have computers and GPS which could calculate this real time with ease. In that case, no time zones would be needed any longer, just UTC and the GPS-Coordinates to calculate real local time. Of course this would also make summer-/wintertime obsolete!

Comment: umm, ok?  doesn't really make much sense to me...

Answer (score 1):

It also makes "day" milestones more difficult to determine. Especially if you live somewhere like I live, where the date would generally change as I'm driving home from work or eating dinner.

- When do you celebrate your birthday?
- What date did you get married on—does this depend on whether you got married in the afternoon or evening? What about weddings that last for several hours between the service and the reception?
- Quite relevant to legal systems, when are you eligible to vote? Voting time will be sunrise to sunset (say), but what if the day changes while the sun is in the sky? Do you have to turn 18 (in the US) on the first date, or can you turn 18 (in the US) on the second date during daylight?
- Does Midnight Mass (for Western Christians who celebrate it) happen at 23:59 UTC, or does it happen at local midnight? If at local midnight, is that local midnight of the 24th or the 25th?

Either way you pick these, they end up a bit odd, and totally contrary to how humans operate and think.

Comment: I don't see any of those being weird. Right now, my birthday is celebrated relative to wherever I'm living, not relative to 2 AM in Texas where I was born. In the new system, there would be one date everywhere, and I would celebrate on that date. Same with marriages, holidays, voting, etc. Nothing has changed. Things like New Year's Eve would be simplified since we'd celebrate it once worldwide instead of watching 24 countdown clocks until we pass out. Things like Midnight Mass would depend on local custom. Just like celebrating at 2400 instead of solar midnight is a custom.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is not so much timezones, but rather keeping accurate clocks and *synchronizing* them across long distances.  Whatever standard you pick doesn't *really* matter so much - it's *having the standard* that makes by far the largest difference.  If it's UTC 3:32 in New Yord and it's UTC 3:32 in Tokyo that's fine - at least you still know what time it is, and it's reasonably convenient.

Before time zones, accurate clocks were expensive (and not that accurate).  Large public clocks formed a local reference for people in a given town or city and those clocks were set by the sun at local noon (often using something like a sextant, same as a sailor would at sea).   This meant that 2:10PM in Chicago was maybe 2:34PM in Cincinati, 1:53PM in Kansas City, 2:42PM in Pittsburg and 3:01PM in Philadelphia, etc.  The chaos came from the train system, where you had to leave one city and catch a train in another, scheduled to leave at a specific local time that was different from the local time you were leaving - possibly moving past several other cities in the meantime.

Rather than a single time reference, you would have needed five or six or more pocketwatches and a spreadsheet of calculations to figure out which train you needed to take to make another at a given time in a given city to be at your destination at the local time you needed to be there.  *That* was the nightmare before timezones.  Standardizing time and *synchronizing* everyone's clocks, doubly so with very accurate clocks, is what makes for functional interaction over long distances.  The particular details of the standard don't really matter - people adjust and get used to whatever that standard is, whether it is their local timezone time, UTC, or Stardate 14352.6.  What matters is that everyone everywhere agrees on what time it is and can communicate that to each other in a clear and easily understandable way.

In a way, a single standard is actually clearer and easier because you need one fewer piece of information - the timezone.  Militaries (and airlines), for example, almost always work on UTC (aka : Zulu) time because their operations are frequently crossing timezones and a single time standard ensures that everyone is absolutely clear on where and when things are happening.

Answer (score 0):

First, we'd still have time zones after a fashion. We'd all have an "offset" to describe how much my time differs from UTC, and how much yours does, then I would subtract my offset from yours and add the offset to my clock to figure out what effective time it is where you live.

For example, I'm in UTC-7 and you're in UTC-5. Yours-Mine = -5-(-7) = -5+7 = 2. So if it's 03:35 here, it's like 05:35 there. Which is what we do already to determine the actual time. So that wouldn't change.

Second, we'd either have a secondary set of local clocks that add our own offset to UTC -- oh wait, that's what we're doing now. Or we wouldn't.

Let's say people were somehow convinced to always use UTC. What would happen?

- People in different parts of the world would think about "9 AM" in different ways. People in Europe/Africa would think of it as morning. People in the Americas would think of it as afternoon. People in Asia would think of it as night.
- People who work a shift where the date changes would have to get used to changing the date in the middle of their shift. Because most people work daylight shifts, this would affect a larger percentage of the population that it currently does.

That's really about it. "9 AM" already means something very different to me than my mom. For me, it's the middle of my sleep cycle. For my mom, she's already eaten breakfast and fed the animals on the farm. Between noon and 7 PM we're both awake, although I'm on the just-woke-up part of my day, and she's on the about-to-go-to-bed part of hers. So we've already fixed that problem: just ask your friends what time they're normally available and on what days, then figure out what part of that window coincides with your availability.

And lots of people already have to deal with date changes midway through their shift. For most people, it's not relevant. If I sign a check or datestamp my logbook with yesterday's date, nobody cares. For people whose jobs requires the correct date, software normally does it for them. Otherwise, they can look at the time. If it says 00:XX or later, it's tomorrow. If it says 23:XX or earlier, it's yesterday. At the beginning of your shift you'd write both dates for easy reference.

You don't even have to convert to a 24-hour format. The AM/PM system is completely unambiguous. There are exactly 24 distinct hours per day. The date changes on the PM -> AM change. It's even in alphabetical order for you.

I would be happy if the AM/PM system didn't follow 11 AM with 12 PM. It needs to be 11 AM -> 0 PM or 11 AM -> 12 AM -> 1 PM (noon), but that's true regardless of timezones or a lack thereof.

Answer (score 0):

All answers so far assume that people keep their current time schedules and change the name of the time they use to UTC or whatever central time unit is used.

When I read your question I assumed you would impose the times of UTC to people wherever in the world.
So they would start working at 9:00 whatever the sun time in that location.

This will work in Europe and much of Africa where the work will still mostly be done in daytime. It will get harder the farther you away from the Greenwich meridian and in East Asia, Australia and Oceania, you will have to work in the middle of the night and be off during the sunlight hours. People will complain about that and rightly so, as most people do not do well working just nights.

One time zone may work on colonized planets where most people never go up the surface, but not where people would go out in daylight as a rule.

Answer (score -1):

Time zones are not man made.  They have always existed. 
The majority of people in the world are awake during daylight hours and asleep when the sun is down.  It is a natural and expected phenomenon.  Ancient sundials exist all over the world including the US and Canada supporting the notion that human beings are highly organized and extremely intelligent creatures.

Comment: Sure time zones are man made, they have not always existed. _Local times_ (as read by a sundial) are not man-made; but for anything where you need synchronised time between remote locations somehow (first necessary with the advent of railways) it's totally impractical if you always need to know the exact longitude difference. That's why sundials got out of use. Time zones already forego local time; as already said, in vast time zones like China this is very notable. Zones are in many ways a poor compromise between proper local time and proper global time.

Comment: to the irritation of engineers and computer scientists, sometimes the best solutions are messy compromises ;-)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: local times are time zones. There just used to be a different time zone for every village, then we condensed it to 30 or 50 or something. And to be fair, it's really not hard to do longitude math. I'm at 111° W = -111°. Let's say my friend is at 83° E = +83°. 83°-(-111°)=+194°. There are 360° in a circle. +194°/360° = +0.539. With 24 hours in a day, thats +0.539*24 hours = +12.9 hours. 0.9 hours is 0.9*60 minutes = 54 minutes if we care. The equation simplifies to (destLong-originLong)/15. Or divide by 3 to an extra digit or two then again by 5 if division by 15 seems hard.