# Single Time Zone in a Galaxy

Tags: physics, time, time-keeping, relativity, time-manipulation

This follows up the [Single Time Zone on a spherical planet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/188469/80091).

Suppose now we have many habitual planets in a Solar system or in a Galaxy.

> How does it work to set up a Universal Time? Will it be feasible to set up a Single Time Zone in a Solar system or in a Galaxy?

Obviously, if the spatial scales are beyond the Solar system,

- the special relativity +spacetime+kinematics) and
- general relativity (+gravity)
- synchronization of clocks when we have high speed travelers,

may be involved.

Comment: While I voted to close as a duplicate using what I suspect is the most likely duplicate, [my own question about deriving a common time between two arbitrary planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/185852/40609) might actually provide the answer you're looking for.

Comment: It is not meaningful to talk about clock synchronization over large distances. At least, not within the boundaries of physics as we know it. In fact, even for our little Solar system defining synchronicity is tricky; see the difference between [Terrestrial Dynamic Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_Time), [Geocentric Coordinate Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocentric_Coordinate_Time) and [Barycentric Coordinate Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_Coordinate_Time), which all flow at different rates.